# FileOutputStream error al generar un PDF en NetBeans

Tags: java, pdf, io

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde utilizo `itext` y `fileoutputstream` para generar un **pdf**, pero al importar la libreria `java.io` me sale un error:

> cannot find symbol class FileOutputStream

¿Cómo puedo corregir este error? Adjunto 2 códigos donde lo importo y donde lo utilizo.

Archivo java, línea 6.

```
package dhinventario;

import java.io.FileOutputStream; //Aquí es donde tira el error.
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

Archivo java, línea 1438.

```
try{
    PdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("facturas/" +
        jTextFieldCodFacturas.getText() + ".pdf" ) ) // ...
    document.open();
```

Comment: Haga un `rebuild` de su proyecto, si persiste el error intentar con `import java.io.*` si no sería  un error de configuración.

Comment: Asegúrate que el JDK esté bien configurado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios voy a intentar lo que mencionan

Comment: tu rt.jar no está en el classpath, asegúrate de configurar bien tu `JAVA_HOME` y de apuntar a un JDK